# incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to Comparable (when passing as a parameter)

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, comparable

I'm having issues right now trying to model a binary search tree with generic data types.  I will eventually be reading in string values and inserting them into the binary tree, hence the string declaration in the Nodez class.  The Nodez class is a class I defined to declare nodes to pass to the search tree.  The string value will be an attribute of this class.  The BSTree is based off a class defined as the following:

```
public class BSTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements BSTreeAPI<E>
```

My issue lies in the main block of code.  The error occurs when I try to insert an instance of the Nodez class.  The exact error here states: "incompatible types: Nodez cannot be converted to Comparable"

I've spent a good amount of time trying to debug this but I am not so great with generics?

Any suggestions please?  Thanks!

```
package twotreesanalyzer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class TwoTreesAnalyzer 
{

    public static class Nodez <E extends Comparable<E>> {
        public String x;
        public E node;

        public String get(){
            return x;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws AVLTreeException, BSTreeException, IOException
    {        

        Function<String, PrintStream> printUpperCase = x -> System.out.printf("%S", x);

        BSTree bstTest = new BSTree();

        Nodez e1 = new Nodez();
        e1.x = "fresh";


        bstTest.insert(e1);

        System.out.println(bstTest.inTree(e1.get()));

    }
}
```

Comment: and how does class `Nodez` look like? does it implement comparable? by the way, it would be a good idea to provide good names to your classes/methods/objects even if it's just a toy project!

Comment: Right.  Nodez is declared above the main.  When it implements comparable, it returns an stating that nodez is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(E) in Comparable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your BSTree is trying to compare your nodez objects, if this is how you want it to function you need to implement Comparible on your Nodez class. I fixed it up quickly with a collections tree as an example.

```
public static class Nodez <E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Nodez<E>>{
        public String x;
        public E node;

        public String get(){
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Nodez<E> node) {
            return node.x.compareTo(x);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {        

        Function<String, PrintStream> printUpperCase = x -> System.out.printf("%S", x);

        TreeSet<Nodez<String>> bstTest = new TreeSet<>();

        Nodez<String> e1 = new Nodez<>();
        e1.x = "fresh";


        bstTest.add(e1);

        System.out.println(bstTest.contains(e1));

    }
```

However I think you were going for the node to be able to accept any generic type that's comparable in which case it should be ordered a bit more like this:

```
public static class Nodez <E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Nodez<E>>{
        public E x;
        public Nodez<E> node;

        public E get(){
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Nodez<E> node) {
            return node.x.compareTo(x);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {        

        Function<String, PrintStream> printUpperCase = x -> System.out.printf("%S", x);

        TreeSet<Nodez<String>> bstTest = new TreeSet<>();

        Nodez<String> e1 = new Nodez<>();
        e1.x = "fresh";


        bstTest.add(e1);

        System.out.println(bstTest.contains(e1));
    }
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote this 100 times... this clears it all up but yes, I'll be passing mostly string types but I was still looking to model it in more general fashion..  Thank you so much; worked like a charm

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.